# Rethinkdb IO reaches 100%

Tags: io, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

`Rethinkdb` IO reaches 100% whenever there is a data upload. The load reaches near about 50. Is this a common phenomenon, or do we need to do some optimizations here?

Comment: Hi @hellodk, under what circumstances is this happening? Could you tell us a little bit more about what you are running RethinkDB on? How are you connecting to it and what the insert code looks like?

Comment: hi @dalanmiller the insert statement used here is:
rethinkdb import -f <FILE NAME>.csv --format csv --table <TABLE NAME> --pkey <PRIMARY KEY> --force
The rethinkdb instance is running on a 14 GB dual core machine

Answer (score 1):

RethinkDB uses a blocker pool to do IO.  On Linux systems, each thread in this blocker pool contributes `1` to the load average while blocking on disk, so RethinkDB sometimes causes the system to report an extremely high load average even under normal load.

Using 100% of your disk throughput is a different story.  If you're running an IO-heavy workload on a slow disk, especially on a rotating drive, then that's pretty reasonable, but it does mean that you might have scaling problems if you want to do more disk-intensive operations.  If you start to have those scaling problems, probably the best solution would be to get a faster disk.

Comment: we're using ssd in our case, plus the task is to add some around 1M rows. I believe this is not a very huge figure to get 100% IO, or is there something which I missed?

Comment: When you say 100% IO, do you mean IOWait, or are you referring to a different statistic?  100% IOWait isn't a problem unless you're also seeing slow performance, it just means that the disk is your bottleneck.  If you're seeing slow performance along with 100% IOWait, I'd check to make sure you have enough RAM and that RethinkDB isn't going into swap.